# Maven - Exclude Plugin from another Plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I've got a plugin that I need to use in my build. This plugin, however, has a build-time dependency on another plugin and that dependency does *not* work post-Java-8.

Specifically, the plugin that I want to use has this in its pom.xml file

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                    <version>${javaVersion}</version>
                    <scope>system</scope>
                    <systemPath>${tools.jar}</systemPath>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    ......
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

It's set to the `test-compile` phase, so it's only ever run when the plugin itself is being built, and not when it's being used.

The problem is that it's got the `systemPath` as part of the dependency, and this is set to something that is not resolvable using Java 9+. That in turn causes the build for the project *using* the plugin to fail with:

```
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.sun:tools:jar must specify an absolute path but is ${tools.jar} @
```

So either I need to completely ignore the `maven-antrun-plugin` as part of my *using* this plugin, or I need to at least make the dependencies for it work.

Any thoughts?

Cheers